# Issues with Props reading undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I was working on my project ([repo](https://github.com/BeauRussell/Codecademy-Jammming) if you want to see the entire code). The application searches with the Spotify API, and lets you store them in a playlist, then save it to your account. I can search the database, and bring up tracks, but when I try to add them to a playlist, I get thrown an error that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` In my Track component on the "This.props.isRemoval" statement in renderAction(). The issue is everything renders fine, including all this.props values. So I logged `this.props.isRemoval` for the entire list, and it logs them all as false, as it should. Any ideas? Track Component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css';


export class Track extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
  this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
 }

 addTrack() {
  this.props.onAdd(this.props.track);
 }

 removeTrack() {
  this.props.onRemove(this.props.track);
 }

 renderAction() {
  if(this.props.isRemoval) {
   this.removeTrack();
  } else {
   this.addTrack();
  }
 }

 render() {
  return(
   <div className="Track">
      <div className="Track-information">
      {console.log(this.props.isRemoval)}
        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        <p>{this.props.artist} | {this.props.album}</p>
      </div>
      <a className="Track-action" onClick={this.renderAction}>+</a>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Track;
```

Also, if you want to take a look at my repo to help me out, I haven't looked into this issue much, but it only let's me search the term "Hello" which may be stored for some reason, since it's the first term I used, but even stopping the node server and restarting it, it locked me to the same keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind your renderAction function in the constructor as you did with:

```
this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this)
this.renderAction  = this.renderAction.bind(this);
```

Comment: That causes me to get the same error, but during compilation, and on the TrackList.js Component instead.`render() {
  12 |  return (
  13 |   <div className="TrackList">
> 14 |       {this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track 
  15 |        key={track.id}
  16 |        name={track.name}
  17 |        artist={track.artist}`

Comment: but the other error is for another code snippet. This answer is for the code you provided